# Downloading .txt file from Dropbox with Java

Tags: java, file, download, dropbox

Hi I am in my final year, doing a project with Java (desktop application). I am writing a java desktop application class to download a .txt file onto the desktop of my computer.
I am having trouble downloading the file from my shared folder in my Dropbox account. I have done the OAuth process and have obtained the token key and secret, but when I use the code given by Dropbox, I get a message saying "The import com.dropbox cannot be resolved" 
  [Picture of The import com.dropbox cannot be resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIeiY.png)

I am using eclipse IDE, it says on Dropbox that I have to install Java SDK, I have downloaded the package, but not sure how to install it. [Picture of the SDK folder downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnV7l.png)

I would be grateful if someone could help me out with the import problem or suggest an easier way to download files from Dropbox to computer.

Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.dropbox.core.DbxAccountInfo;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthFinish;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxClient;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxEntry;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxException;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthNoRedirect;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxWriteMode;

public class Dropbox {

    private static final String DROP_BOX_APP_KEY = "<redacted>";
    private static final String DROP_BOX_APP_SECRET = "<redacted>";
    DbxClient dbxClient;

    public DbxClient authDropbox(String dropBoxAppKey, String dropBoxAppSecret)
            throws IOException, DbxException {
        DbxAppInfo dbxAppInfo = new DbxAppInfo(dropBoxAppKey, dropBoxAppSecret);
        DbxRequestConfig dbxRequestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig(
                "JavaDropboxTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
        DbxWebAuthNoRedirect dbxWebAuthNoRedirect = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(
                dbxRequestConfig, dbxAppInfo);
        String authorizeUrl = dbxWebAuthNoRedirect.start();
        System.out.println("1. Authorize: Go to URL and click Allow : "
                + authorizeUrl);
        System.out
                .println("2. Auth Code: Copy authorization code and input here ");
        String dropboxAuthCode = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in)).readLine().trim();
        DbxAuthFinish authFinish = dbxWebAuthNoRedirect.finish(dropboxAuthCode);
        String authAccessToken = authFinish.accessToken;
        dbxClient = new DbxClient(dbxRequestConfig, authAccessToken);
        System.out.println("Dropbox Account Name: "
                + dbxClient.getAccountInfo().displayName);

        return dbxClient;
    }

    /* returns Dropbox size in GB */
    public long getDropboxSize() throws DbxException {
        long dropboxSize = 0;
        DbxAccountInfo dbxAccountInfo = dbxClient.getAccountInfo();
        // in GB :)
        dropboxSize = dbxAccountInfo.quota.total / 1024 / 1024 / 1024;
        return dropboxSize;
    }

    public void uploadToDropbox(String fileName) throws DbxException,
            IOException {
        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        try {
            DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = dbxClient.uploadFile("/" + fileName,
                    DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), fis);
            String sharedUrl = dbxClient.createShareableUrl("/" + fileName);
            System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString() + " URL "
                    + sharedUrl);
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }
    }

    public void createFolder(String folderName) throws DbxException {
        dbxClient.createFolder("/" + folderName);
    }

    public void listDropboxFolders(String folderPath) throws DbxException {
        DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = dbxClient
                .getMetadataWithChildren(folderPath);
        System.out.println("Files List:");
        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
        }
    }

    public void downloadFromDropbox(String fileName) throws DbxException,
            IOException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        try {
            DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = dbxClient.getFile("/" + fileName,
                    null, outputStream);
            System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
        JavaDropbox javaDropbox = new JavaDropbox();
        javaDropbox.authDropbox(DROP_BOX_APP_KEY, DROP_BOX_APP_SECRET);
        System.out.println("Dropbox Size: " + javaDropbox.getDropboxSize()
                + " GB");
        javaDropbox.uploadToDropbox("happy.png");
        javaDropbox.createFolder("tutorial");
        javaDropbox.listDropboxFolders("/");
        javaDropbox.downloadFromDropbox("happy.png");

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to import the correct classes. Normally an IDE will offer a suggestion to add the import, but if it cannot then you probably have jar files missing.

Comment: Import issues aside, it looks like you're using the [API v1 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/java). [API v1 is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) though. You should use the [API v2 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java) instead. We recommend [installing that using Maven or Gradle](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java#setup).